# Import Text File into Excel

Tags: excel

Suppose I have the following data in a text file:

`1,2,3,4;5;6,7,8;9`

`11,12,13,14;15;16,17,18;19`

I'd want the data to look like this:

```
1 2 3 4 7 8

      5   9

      6

11 12 13 14 17 18

         15    19

         16
```

I'm wondering if Excel can do that, or if I need to create the source text file differently, or write some macro to do it.

Does anyone know if Excel can support importing something like this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Import a csv with multiple delimiters?

Comment: Need to work on formatting your example a bit.

Comment: Excel can't do that without VBA. If you have control over the text file format then it might be easier to adjust that.

Answer (score 0):

You might try importing "as is" (one cell each for your two examples) then Find & Select, Replace..., Find what: `,` Replace with: `,=` Replace All, then Find what: `;`, Replace with: `&char(10)&`, Replace All. Then Text to Columns (DATA > Data Tools), Delimited, Comma and format the results (HOME > Cells - Format, Format Cells...) with Wrap text.